# Advantages of Angular built in services

Tags: angularjs

Is there an underlying reason why I should use Angular 1 $ services for my code?  I realize they wrap $digest but it seems trivial to kick off myself?

I'm in a environment where I can rely on native calls, I'd much rather use built in promises and http fetch rather than $q and $http then just trigger the digest myself.

Am I missing out on much? This seems to be how zone.js works in Angular 2?

Comment: To make angular known about changes are made to model and update view. To update view on change in model you need to trigger digest cycle, which is heart of angular 1.

Comment: Triggering the digest is one reason. Making your code testable thanks to DI and to the mock services angular provides is another reason. Making your angular code look like any other canonical angular code, thus easily understandable by any angular developer other than yourself is a third one.